# Are browser event callbacks considered tasks?

Tags: javascript

Are browser event callbacks considered tasks in the same way that promise `.then`, `.catch` callbacks operate. IE. they go in a task queue? or even the same task queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are put into a list for later execution. So if you consider "task" the correct terminology for that process, then yes.

For events added through addEventListener()

> https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget
>
> Each EventTarget object has an associated [event listener list](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget-event-listener-list) (a list
>   of zero or more event listeners). It is initially the empty list.
>
> ...
>
> The event listener is appended to target’s event listener list and is not appended if >it has the same type, callback, and capture.

For promises then() calls

> https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen
>
> 7. If the value of promise's [[PromiseState]] internal slot is "pending",
>
>    a. Append fulfillReaction as the last element of the [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) that is the value of promise's [[PromiseFulfillReactions]] internal slot.
>
>    b. Append rejectReaction as the last element of the [List](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type) that is the value of promise's [[PromiseRejectReactions]] internal slot.